# Creating a velocity vector for a point

Tags: python, graphics

New to Python. After working in graphics.py for a little bit I have something along the lines of

```
if (a.x-b.x)**2 + (a.y-b.y)**2 <= a.radius**2:
   vec_a_b = b-a 
   a.velocity = normalized(vec_a_b)*a.velocity.magnitude

circ1.x += circ1.velocity.x
circ1.y += circ1.velocity.y
```

In order for this to work however, a velocity vector for point `a` that describes its speed and direction are needed.
How would I go about doing so?

I should also mention that the end goal is to have a point `a` move towards point `b`, once point `b` is within the radius of point `a`'s circle, if that's worth anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

**edit**: the circle is drawn around point `a` with point `a` as its center.

Comment: I am also getting the error `AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'x'`. How do I solve this issue? I'm likely missing something blatantly obvious.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].